# Can I get iis7 to ignore the utf8 bom?

Tags: iis-7, utf-8, notepad

Any UTF8 BOM on an included file is forwarded to the browser and ruins layout (which means any editing with notepad is impossible).

Can I learn IIS7 not to forward the BOM?

Comment: Consider using a better editor, such as Visual Studio.

Comment: @SLaks, Satisfied with netbeans, but that's another story...